# Last transaction date in group by statements

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

On executing the below query I am getting the minimum date across every month. However, I need the minimum date across the entire data range.

```
Select month(b.created_at), a.user_id, sum(a.payout), min(date(created_at))
from transaction as a
inner join partner_transaction as b on
a.partner_transaction_id = b.id where a.status = "Paid" and date(b.created_at) >= "2020-08-01"
group by month(b.created_at)
```

Example:

transaction:

| Transaction ID | User ID | Status | payout |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | Paid | 1000 | 12/01/21 |
| 2 | 102 | Paid | 1000 | 13/01/21 |
| 3 | 103 | Paid | 1000 | 14/01/21 |
| 4 | 101 | Paid | 1000 | 15/01/21 |
| 5 | 102 | Paid | 1000 | 16/01/21 |
| 6 | 103 | Paid | 1000 | 17/01/21 |
| 7 | 101 | Paid | 1000 | 12/02/21 |
| 8 | 102 | Paid | 1000 | 13/02/21 |
| 9 | 103 | Paid | 1000 | 14/03/21 |

partner_transaction:

| Transaction ID | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/01/21 |
| 2 | 13/01/21 |
| 3 | 14/01/21 |
| 4 | 15/02/21 |
| 5 | 16/02/21 |
| 6 | 17/02/21 |
| 7 | 12/02/21 |
| 8 | 13/02/21 |
| 9 | 14/02/21 |

Desired result:

| Month | User ID | Total For Month | Oldest Transaction All Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 2000 | 12/01/21 |
| 1 | 102 | 2000 | 13/01/21 |
| 1 | 103 | 2000 | 14/01/21 |
| 2 | 101 | 1000 | 12/01/21 |
| 2 | 102 | 1000 | 13/01/21 |
| 2 | 103 | 1000 | 14/01/21 |

Comment: Please add sample data to your question to make it more clear.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? If you are using v8+ you can use windowed functions, e.g. `min(min(date(created_at))) OVER()`

Comment: Got this error - Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(group by user_id) from transaction as a inner join partner_transaction as b on ' at line 1


Query I used - Select month(b.created_at), a.user_id, sum(a.payout), min(min(date(created_at))) over (group by user_id)
from transaction as a
inner join partner_transaction as b on
a.partner_transaction_id = b.id where a.status = "Paid" and date(b.created_at) >= "2020-08-01"
group by month(b.created_at)

Comment: Your query is invalid. You group by month, but select a user. Which user? Do you expect there to be exactly one user per month? `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` in order to prevent yourself from writing invalid queries.

Comment: Please show us what your result is supposed to look like. Do you want one result row per user? Per month? Per user and month? Only one result row at all? ... Show sample data and expected result to make it easy to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I used this query - Select month(b.created_at), a.user_id, sum(a.payout), min(min(date(created_at))) over (group by user_id)
from transaction as a
inner join partner_transaction as b on
a.partner_transaction_id = b.id where a.status = "Paid" and date(b.created_at) >= "2020-08-01"
group by month(b.created_at), a.user_id

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Copy the sample data for the two tables plus the expected result as text into your request instead. You can use a tool like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to format table data.

Comment: Tab 1
+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| TransactionID  | User Id | Status | Payout |
+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
|              1 |     101 | Paid   |    100 |
|              2 |     102 | Paid   |    100 |
|              3 |     103 | Paid   |     59 |
|              4 |     104 | Paid   |     80 |
|              5 |     105 | Paid   |     90 |
|              6 |     106 |        |        |
+----------------+---------+--------+--------+

Tab 2

Comment: Tab 2

Tab 2

+----------------+------------+
| TransactionID  | created_at |
+----------------+------------+
|              1 | 12-Jan     |
|              2 | 15-Jan     |
|              3 | 18-Jan     |
|              4 | 10-Feb     |
|              5 | 15-Feb     |
|              6 | 20-Feb     |
+----------------+------------+

Comment: expected o/p


+--------+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| Month  | User iD | payout | First date of transaction |
+--------+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| Jan    |     101 |    100 | 12-Jan                    |
| Jan    |     102 |    100 | 15-Jan                    |
| Jan    |     103 |     59 | 18-Jan                    |
| Feb    |     101 |     80 | 12-Jan                    |
| Feb    |     102 |     90 | 15-Jan                    |
| Feb    |     103 |     80 | 18-Jan                    |
+--------+---------+--------+----------------

Comment: I brought your example data in the image into native tables in the post and I tried to come up with an example of what your desired output is. You should take a look at it now and modify the "Desired Result" table to match what you really want. I'm not quite sure I interpreted your question correctly.